# why discharging capacitor voltage in a rc circuit is positive? why it should not be negative?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, remote-control

[image]

During discharging, the direction of the current is opposite to the original current direction(source current).so the current is negative. likewise the discharging voltage direction is also opposite to the source voltage direction. then why the discharging capacitor voltage in a rc circuit is positive? why it should not be negative?

Comment: we mentioned the voltage of battery/capacitor, not the voltage across R. If Vr is defined by potential left-pin-R minus right-pin-R, Vr positive when charge, and negative when discharge

Answer (score 3):

No, only the *current* is moving in the opposite direction. The voltage across is still the same polarity, decreasing to 0.

Comment: In general, Negative voltage represents what?

Comment: It means a voltage below ground potential.

Comment: thank you.i am referring this answer http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10322/what-is-negative-voltage

Comment: In a rc discharging circuit. I think the voltage across the resistor is negative.